# writing a differential equation but i dont understand the answer someone gave if someone could help explain?

Tags: calculus, differential

they used compound interest formula for doing constant rate of population growth. the gave this answer for the differential equation. i want to understand what they did/ how they did it.

A differential equation including initial conditions.

$$P = P(0) (1+r)^t$$

$$\frac{dP}{dt} = P(0)  \cdot \ln{(1+r)}  \cdot (1+r)^t$$

$$\frac{dP}{dt} = k (1+r)^t$$

can someone explain what they did each step I feel like I'm missing something

Comment: Derivative of $a^x$ w.r.t. $x$ is $a^x ln(a)$. The first step follows from there.

Comment: ok im dumb thank you

Comment: @tom what are the x that appear in the second equation? do you mean a product?

Comment: yes ( P(0) ) * ( ln(1+r) ) * (1+r)^t

Comment: @user812951 : Could you type $a^x\ln a$ or $a^x\ln(a)$ instead of $a^x ln(a)$? The code is `a^2\ln a` or `a^x\ln(a)`. That is standard usage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

\begin{align*}
\frac d{dt} a^t = {} & \lim_{h\to0} \frac{a^{t+h} - a^t} h \\[2pt]
& \text{(definition of “derivative”)} \\[10pt]
= {} & \lim_{h\to0}\left( a^t\cdot \frac {a^h-1} h \right) \\[10pt]
= {} & a^t\cdot\lim_{h\to0} \frac{a^h -1 } h \\[2pt]
& \text{since $a^t$ does not depend on $h$} \\[10pt]
= {} & \big(a^t \times\text{constant}\big) \\
& \text{since the limit does not depend on $t$}
\end{align*}

Just what the “constant” is can be seen via the chain rule if one knows that the constant is $1$ when $a=e\approx 2.71828\ldots\,$:

\begin{align}
\frac d {dt} a^t = {} & \frac d {dt} e^{t\ln a} = e^{t\ln a}\cdot \frac d {dt} (t\ln a) \\[10pt]
= {} & a^t \ln a.
\end{align}

And here you see what is “natural” about $e$: It is the base for which this “constant” is $1.$

Comment: ok so that part makes sense.
 when dP/dt=k(1+r)t k is representing p(0)? or whats is happening to make it k(1+r)^t
sorry I'm still trying to learn the formatting.

Comment: @tom : When $t=0$ then $k(1+r)^t = k. \qquad$

Answer (score 0):

Given
$P = P_o (1+r)^t$

I'll apply natural logarithm on both sides of the equation

$\ln P = \ln (P_o (1+r)^t)$

$\ln P = \ln P_o + t\ln (1+r)$

Then I'll differentiate the equation both sides

$\frac{dP}{P} = 0 + \ln (1+r) dt$

$\frac{dP}{P} = \ln (1+r) dt$

$\frac{dP}{dt} = P\ln (1+r)$

but $P = P_o (1+r)^t$

thus
$\frac{dP}{dt} = P_o (1+r)^t\ln (1+r)$

$\frac{dP}{dt} = P_o\ln (1+r) (1+r)^t$

but $P_o\ln (1+r) = k$ where by $k$ is constant

therefore
$\frac{dP}{dt} = k (1+r)^t$